# Decrypt file in java failing on hash verification

Tags: java, aes, encryption

I am using this sample from code project - C# implementation of encryption,  in java

[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8633/File-Encryption-Decryption-with-Hash-Verification?msg=2175833#xx2175833xx](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8633/File-Encryption-Decryption-with-Hash-Verification?msg=2175833#xx2175833xx%20CodeProject)

On decryption, file gets decrypted but on verifying current hash with old hash, the last few bytes of old hash are zeros and the verification fails.

My java implementation of decrypt is this:

```
 private void mDecrypt_File(FileInputStream fin, String outFile) throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    byte[] len = new byte[8];
    byte[] FC_TAGBuffer = new byte[8];

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_INSTANCE);

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fin);

    dis.read(iv, 0, 16);
    dis.read(salt, 0, 16);

    Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(DEFAULT_PASSWORD, salt, F_ITERATIONS);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(rfc.getBytes(32), "AES");

    //decryption code
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    CipherInputStream cIn = new CipherInputStream(dis, cipher);

    cIn.read(len, 0, 8);
    long lSize = getLong(len, 0);

    cIn.read(FC_TAGBuffer, 0, 8);

    byte[] tempFC_TAGBuffer = changeByteArray(FC_TAGBuffer, 0);//new byte[8];                           

    BigInteger ulong = new BigInteger(1, tempFC_TAGBuffer);

    if (!ulong.equals(FC_TAG)) {
        Exception ex = new Exception("Tags are not equal");
        throw ex;
    }

    byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    //determine number of reads to process on the file                          
    long numReads = lSize / BUFFER_SIZE;
    // determine what is left of the file, after numReads                   
    long slack = (long) lSize % BUFFER_SIZE;

    int read = -1;
    int value = 0;
    int outValue = 0;

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    md.reset();
    // read the buffer_sized chunks         
    for (int i = 0; i < numReads; ++i) {
        read = cIn.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        fout.write(bytes, 0, read);
        md.update(bytes, 0, read);
        value += read;
        outValue += read;
    }
    // now read the slack                   
    if (slack > 0) {
        read = cIn.read(bytes, 0, (int) slack);
        fout.write(bytes, 0, read);
        md.update(bytes, 0, read);
        value += read;
        outValue += read;
    }
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();
    byte[] curHash = md.digest();

    byte[] oldHash = new byte[md.getDigestLength()];
    read = cIn.read(oldHash, 0, oldHash.length);
    if (oldHash.length != read || (!CheckByteArrays(oldHash, curHash))) {
        Exception ex = new Exception("File Corrupted!");
        throw ex;
    }
    if (outValue != lSize) {
        Exception ex = new Exception("File Sizes don't match!");
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

This decrypt method works on android but it does not work in simple java project.
File is being encrypted from Java/Android or .NET.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error / Exception?

Comment: read = cIn.read(oldHash, 0, oldHash.length);
This line reads the remaining bytes from cIn is not equal to the current hash.
So the check
 if (oldHash.length != read || (!CheckByteArrays(oldHash, curHash)))
fails.

Lets say if we have 5 bytes of data, after decryption, the old hash (which should be of 32 bytes length) will be of 27 bytes length and the renaming bytes in old hash are zeros.

Comment: So, you can't read enough bytes? Trace your code, and examine your input data.

Comment: If you have no more idea, I can just repeat myself: take the saem code and input for Java and Android, and debug them side-by-side, and compare what's going wrong.

Comment: I did that debugging on .NET and JAVA side by side, the values of hash bytes are different but .NET gets the oldhash and currhash exactly same but in JAVA the last few bytes are zero (the zeros are exactly equals to the length of data). If you want to try I can post encrypt method too.

Comment: On debugging more, I observed that the old hash is being calculated correctly only if the data(actual size of unencypted file) is multiples of 32 ie 32/64/96/128 ... 
I must be using the streams wrongly. Please help me understanding this behavior.